# Swift 5 - Need help reloading web view on view controller 1 after user clicks tab bar button for the second time

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, swift5, tabbarcontroller

I've been stuck this for maybe over 30 hours in the past week trying to figure this out and can't seem to get this right. I have a Swift 5 iOS application. It has a tab bar view controller with 3 tabs / view controllers. All my code is stored on one viewcontroller file. Below is the code for the tab bar and first view controller, all the other view controllers are structure similarly.

Expected: when user clicks twice on a tab, then we will store the number of times they clicked in variable called VariableRefresh. When that variable gets to 2 then we will refresh the web view on the view controller.

When I click tab bar twice for view controller 1, then the debug print message gets fired, which tells me that the tab bar getting clicked twice was successful, but the web view does not refresh. I get error message saying that web view is returning nil and to make it optional value. so I add ? to the web view to make it optional value but the problem is web view is still nil, and it does not refresh/ reload. the func reload should be called when the tab bar is pressed twice by the user, and it should execute the function in view controller 1 func reload().

```html
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import FBAudienceNetwork
import WebKit

//we will use this to identifiy if two click are made on this tab, we will put if then statement to monitor clicks and if 2 taps ont he tab, then we will refresh the view controller 1 webview.
var VariableRefresh = 0


//variable for url
let url1 = URL(string:"http://tesla1.social-goat.com")
//variable for url request
let request = URLRequest(url: url1!)





class TabBarClass: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate  {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        debugPrint("Message - TabBarClass - viewDidLoad")
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        let selectedIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController)!
        if selectedIndex == 0 {
          debugPrint("Message - loaded func tabBarController")
            VariableRefresh += 1
            
            if VariableRefresh == 2
            {
            let sendValue = ViewController1();
            sendValue.reload()
            
            }
        }


        
    }
    
}

//################  view controller 1 - Groups START
class ViewController1: UIViewController,FBAdViewDelegate{
    
   
    let url1 = URL(string:"http://tesla1.social-goat.com")
    //
  
    @IBOutlet var webView1: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView_home: GADBannerView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //moved request to the parent level so that viewcontroller1 and tab bar view controller can access
      //  let request = URLRequest(url: url1!)
        debugPrint("Message - viewDidLoad")
        //load request for webview
        webView1.load(request)
        //allow webvie to have back and forward browsing function by swip left or right
        webView1.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView1.navigationDelegate = self
        webView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       
        
     //banner id ca-app-pub-8404457641397226/8691324688
    //test banner id ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2435281174
    // Replace this ad unit ID with your own ad unit ID.
    bannerView_home.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8404457641397226/8691324688"
    bannerView_home.rootViewController = self
        
    //lets load the admob banner
        loadBannerAd()
        
       
 
        }
    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }
   //this will be called from tab bar view, the problem here is that webview will come up as nil. putting ? or ! still does not reload the webview.
    func reload(){
        webView1.load(request)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        debugPrint("Viewwillapper")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url1!)
        //reload webview when you navigate back to the view controller 1 tab
        webView1.load(request)
        
        
    }
    
   
  
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      // Note loadBannerAd is called in viewDidAppear as this is the first time that
      // the safe area is known. If safe area is not a concern (eg your app is locked
      // in portrait mode) the banner can be loaded in viewDidLoad.
     
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(
      to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator
    ) {
      coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.loadBannerAd()
      })
    }

    func loadBannerAd() {

      // Here safe area is taken into account, hence the view frame is used after the
      // view has been laid out.
      let frame = { () -> CGRect in
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
          return view.frame.inset(by: view.safeAreaInsets)
        } else {
          return view.frame
        }
      }()
      let viewWidth = frame.size.width

      // Here the current interface orientation is used. If the ad is being preloaded
      // for a future orientation change or different orientation, the function for the
      // relevant orientation should be used.
      bannerView_home.adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(viewWidth)

      bannerView_home.load(GADRequest())
    }
    
}


//################  view controller 1 - Groups END
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call let sendValue = ViewController1(); you create completely new instance of the view controller that is disconnected from your implementation. Try to replace let sendValue = ViewController1(); with let sendValue =   tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as ViewController1! in your tab bar controller class. Then you should able to call sendValue.reload(). I've missed it first time that you try to call reload from different class.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for your response. I replaced the  
func reload(){
        webView1.load(request)    }     


With

Comment: With 
    func reload(){
        webView1.load(request)
        webView1.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView1.navigationDelegate = self
        webView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true}
And I still get a nil error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional" for webView.load(request). What I am trying to do is when a user clicks the tab button twice it will reload the webview. I want to do this with each of my 3 tab buttons, If user is on tab one, and press tab 1 twice then it should reload the webview.

Comment: Im rereading your answer, so are you saying I should call webView1.load(request) directly from the tab bar controller class? if so how would I do that as the web view is on the view controller 1 class. I tried to create a IB connection on tabbar class, but when I drag a connection from the web view on view controller 1 and try to drag it to tabbar class it wont let me drop the connection for the webview in the tab bar class.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code now into code editor so I see it more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

When you call `let sendValue = ViewController1();` you create completely new instance of the view controller that is disconnected from your implementation.

Try to replace `let sendValue = ViewController1();` with `let sendValue = 
 tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as ViewController1!` in your tab bar controller class. Then you should able to call `sendValue.reload()`.

I've missed it first time that you try to call reload from different class.

Comment: OMG Thank you Thank you MARKO!!!! YOUR THE BEST! sorry for shouting im just so excited that you got this working for me, and more Important, you made me learn something new about the "created new instance of viewcontroller1". I never knew that could happen, now im researching more into this. Many Many Thanks again!! Cheers! :)